# How to disable specific animation in Android UI test

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I am struggling with disabling the animation when running the UI tests.
This solution however doesn't work and the animation is stil being played:
https://medium.com/@balachandarkm/disable-animations-while-running-android-ui-tests-2d1748280156

So on the physical device the animations are turned off, I've also tried to do that from the code using custom test rule and it still doesn't work:

```
class DisableAnimationsRule : TestRule {
    override fun apply(base: Statement, description: Description): Statement {
        return object : Statement() {
            @Throws(Throwable::class)
            override fun evaluate() {
                // disable animations for test run
                changeAnimationStatus(enable = false)
                try {
                    base.evaluate()
                } finally {
                    // enable after test run
                    changeAnimationStatus(enable = true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun changeAnimationStatus(enable: Boolean = true) {
        with(UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())) {
            executeShellCommand("settings put global transition_animation_scale ${if (enable) 1 else 0}")
            executeShellCommand("settings put global window_animation_scale ${if (enable) 1 else 0}")
            executeShellCommand("settings put global animator_duration_scale ${if (enable) 1 else 0}")
        }
    }
}
```

So the actual code for the animations is like this. I have a custom view, which overrides certain methods:

```
    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        startAnimation()
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        stopAnimation()
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    }

    override fun setVisibility(visibility: Int) {
        super.setVisibility(visibility)
        if (visibility == VISIBLE) startAnimation() else stopAnimation()
    }

    private fun startAnimation() {
        if (!isAttachedToWindow || VISIBLE != visibility) return
        run(
            this, R.anim.pointer_down,
            afterAnimation = {
                run(
                    this, R.anim.pointer_up,
                    afterAnimation = {
                        startAnimation()
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    }

    private fun stopAnimation() {
        clearAnimation()
    }
}
```

My util `run` method is like below:

```
inline fun <reified T : View> run(
        view: T,
        @AnimRes anim: Int,
        crossinline beforeAnimation: (T) -> Unit = { _ -> },
        crossinline afterAnimation: (T) -> Unit = { _ -> }
    ) {
        view.clearAnimation()
        view.startAnimation(
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.context, anim).apply {
                setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
                    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
                        beforeAnimation(view)
                    }

                    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {}
                    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                        afterAnimation(view)
                    }
                })
            }
        )
    }
```

Is there any solution to disable that?

Comment: I believe, the rule doesn't disable *all* animations since Android has a clusterf**ck of animation frameworks (three last time I counted), one of them is kinda ignored by the rule. Specifically view.startAnimation being one of them. What the rule disables are transition animations and whatnot, _sadly_.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `animationsDisabled` to true in the gradle `testOptions`? https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/TestOptions#animationsDisabled:kotlin.Boolean